# Как правильно применить e.preventDefault?

Tags: jquery

Как применить `e.preventDefault();` только для того `li`, у которого есть вложенный `ul`?

**[Вот пример на jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wpkta7r1/2/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(function($) {    
    var parentLi = $('.left_menu > li'), insertUl = $('.left_menu > li > ul');
    $('.sub-menu').prevUntil('li')
    .css("background-color", "red")

    parentLi.click(function(e) {
        // кликнули по ссылке, являющейся непосредственным потомком parentLi
        is_clicked_first_level_link = $(e.target).closest('li').is($(this));
        // кликнули по parentLi, у которого есть вложенное .sub-menu
        has_sub_menu = $(this).has('ul').length;
        if (has_sub_menu && is_clicked_first_level_link) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).find(insertUl).slideToggle();
        }
    });
});
```

**[Посмотреть ваш обновленный пример](http://jsfiddle.net/wpkta7r1/9/)**